# How to make a div fit 100% of a mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

When a user clicks the "burger nav" in the mobile version, whatever item they select, a popup will appear and my problem is that the popup doesn't fit there whole screen and scrolling. When you scroll down, it reveals a portion that isn't apart of the popup. It works fine when the users phone is position vertically because I added "height: 100vh" to the popup in the media query. But when the users phone is position horizontally, it doesn't work. I Tried everything and I cannot fix it. I added "position: fixed" which seemed to work but when you scroll down it would be there but does away when you keep scrolling which is not what I want.Ibasically want for when a user scrolls down on the mobile, for the popup to be responsive and stay 100% height. Here is my code which is uploaded to a code pen.

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWyKaE
```

CSS WHEN HORIZONTAL

```
@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    #burger-nav{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: url(burgerlogo.png) no-repeat 98% center;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
         background-color: white;

    }
    #burger-nav.show{
        background-color: #f97072;
    }
     #nav-menu{
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0;  
        padding:0;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
         display: none;

    }
    #nav-menu.open{
        display: block;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #nav-menu li{
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;  
        top:0;
        left:0;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 0.1px solid #f8f9fb;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    #nav-menu li:hover {
        background-color: #f8f9fb;
    }
    #name-div{ 
        position: absolute;
        top: 8%;
        left: 0%;
        z-index: 10; 
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;

            }
    #name.show{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
        .bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
                top:100px;
                left: 300px;
            }
        .bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
                left: 100px;
                top:100px; 

            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
                left: 200px;
                top:0px; 

            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
                left: 150px;
                top:200px; 
            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
                left: 250px;
                top:200px; 
            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
                left: 250px;
                top:200px; 
            }
         #job-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

           #x-div1{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div1:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon1{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #job-box1{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #job-text1{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Job CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        #contact-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div2{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div2:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon2{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #contact-box2{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #contact-text2{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Contact CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    #press-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div3{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div3:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon3{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #press-box3{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #press-text3{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Legal CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    #legal-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div4{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div4:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon4{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #legal-box4{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #legal-text4{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Legal CSS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
    #support-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div5{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div5:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon5{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #support-box5{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #support-text5{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
}
```

CSS WHEN VERTICAL

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    #burger-nav{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: url(burgerlogo.png) no-repeat 98% center;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
         background-color: white;

    }
    #burger-nav.show{
        background-color: #f97072;
    }
     #nav-menu{
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0;  
        padding:0;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
         display: none;

    }
    #nav-menu.open{
        display: block;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #nav-menu li{
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;  
        top:0;
        left:0;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 0.1px solid #f8f9fb;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    #nav-menu li:hover {
        background-color: #f8f9fb;
    }
    #name-div{ 
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 0%;
        z-index: 10; 
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;

            }
    #name{
        font-size: 4em;
    }
    #name.show{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
        .bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
                top:100px;
                left: 300px;
            }
        .bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
                left: 100px;
                top:400px; 

            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
                left: 200px;
                top:0px; 

            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
                left: 150px;
                top:200px; 
            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
                left: 250px;
                top:200px; 
            }
    .bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
                left: 250px;
                top:200px; 
            }
         #job-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div1{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div1:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon1{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #job-box1{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #job-text1{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top:6%;
            left:0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Job CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        #contact-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

            #x-div2{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div2:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon2{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #contact-box2{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #contact-text2{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top:6%;
            left:0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Contact CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    #press-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

           #x-div3{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div3:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon3{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #press-box3{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #press-text3{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top:6%;
            left:0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Legal CSS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    #legal-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

           #x-div4{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div4:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon4{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #legal-box4{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #legal-text4{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top:6%;
            left:0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
/* End of Legal CSS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
    #support-popup{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 102;
                background: hsla(0,0%,97%,.7);
                display: none;
                }

           #x-div5{
                width: 70px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                 background: #1e1e1e;
                opacity: 0.3;
                border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                left:0px;
                top:1%;
                z-index: 1000;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
            }
            #x-div5:hover{
                background-color: rgb(218, 85, 47);
            }
        #xicon5{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1002;
            bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
        }
        #support-box5{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: none;


        }
        #support-text5{
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top:6%;
            left:0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `vh` and `vw` units to do this. These units will size the content in relation to the size of the viewport. For example:

```
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

If the `vh` and `vw` fields are not supported on the browser your working with, you will need to do it in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $(‘#somediv’).css({‘height’: vph + ‘px’});
}
```

*You can check browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: WAIT actually it worked O_O But it seems like when i went back to the vertically, that one get Messed up but let me check

Comment: Actually nvm I had a typo :D Thank you so much

Comment: @thatoneguy90 unfortunately if these units are not supported by the browser your working with (such as some mobile browsers), you will need to use javascript to achieve it. I update the answer with some code that might help you